# convert T-sql cursor to oracle cursor: FETCH_STATUS equivalent in Oracle cursor

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, cursor

I need to to convert following T-SQL cursor to PL-SQL cursor:

```
DECLARE employe_cur CURSOR 
FOR
SELECT name FROM #table 
where salary = 0
OPEN employe_cur
 FETCH NEXT FROM employe_cur
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  FETCH NEXT FROM employe_cur
END
CLOSE employe_cur
DEALLOCATE employe_cur
```

Most of the part is pretty straight forward but how to convert this

```
 @@ FETCH_STATUS <> -1
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you do it in Oracle (one of the many ways):

```
   OPEN employees_cur;

   LOOP
      ...do your fetches here

      EXIT WHEN employees_cur%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE employees_cur;
```

Comment: so the "employe_cur%NOTFOUND" represents "@@fetch_status <> -1" right??